# Proper way to include react js in wordpress roots theme

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-theming

https://roots.io/

I am using the Wordpress roots theme for the first time and also bower for first time. I want to include react js in my theme and was just wondering the correct steps to take.

I ran "bower install --save react"...

So I now have "react" folder at "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/bower_components"

I need it to load 2 files:

"/wp-content/themes/mytheme/bower_components/react/react.min.js"

"/wp-content/themes/mytheme/bower_components/react/JSXTransformer.js"

From here I am not sure the correct steps, I edited the "bower.json" file directly like so...

```
"overrides": {
  "modernizr": {
    "main": "./modernizr.js"
  },
  "react":{
    "main":[
      "./react.min.js",
      "./JSXTransformer.js"
    ]
  }
},
```

Then I edited the file at "wp-content/themes/mytheme/lib/assets.php" like so...

```
wp_enqueue_script('react', asset_path('scripts/react.js'), [], null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('JSXTransformer', asset_path('scripts/JSXTransformer.js'), [], null, true);
```

It is not loading. And how can I change the "type" parameter on the JSXTransformer script to be "text/jsx"

Answer (score 0):

Im not using wordpress so this answer would be based on assumption, but on my experience with bower, you dont need to require the files after being compiled. you can directly call it depends on how they defined the variable. you will just need to require the compiled file.

so for react they use it like `React`

and there you can add it on your code like

```
React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>blah</div>;
  }
})
```

hope it helps